# WooCommerce Single variation Product Price not showing below the dropdown

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

Please check the screenshot and tell me how I can show the single variation product price below the dropdown.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/aow01b

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: It's preferable that you don't put your entire question text in an image; you can use the image to point out things, but you have two paragraphs of text in there that no one is going to see.

Answer (score 11):

@Junaid, to show variation price even if all variations are the same price or you have just a single variation price try with below code in your theme's **functions.php**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_show_variation_price', function() {return true;});
```

Comment: I can confirm, that the code provided is working in WooCommerce 3.0+